# How can we improve our AWS OpenSearch performance?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, aws-elasticsearch

We are using AWS OpenSearch to ingest and merge data and see that the process is quite slow. Wondering if someone here can help:

Essentially we have 850 GB of data, 400 MM rows with indexing on a subset of the attributes already added to OpenSearch.

When we try to merge (or insert if match not found) it with another data provider, 220 MM rows based on 2 of those indexed attributes, the process is quite slow.

Our Open Search configuration:

3 Master nodes.

20 Data nodes.
We have 1 replica. Didnt see too much difference keeping the replicas at 0, so just wanted to be on the safer side.

r6g.large.search machines.

60 shards, we think it is too much, but right now not sure if it is worth restarting the process. Or changing it on active instances is worth the risk.

Refresh interval is 900 sec. We are OK that indexing happens at a slower pace.

CPU utilization looks OK. Memory utilization also seems fine.

Indexing rate is at 4-8K Ops/min. Search rate at 170K-200K Ops/min (we think this is quite slow and don't know how to increase it linearly)

The process is running in bulk with 100 threads running on each of the three instances and each bulk operation with 500 rows.

Right now, it shows taking ~4 days for the operation to finish. The deleted documents(based on the merge) is like 1.5 MM records/hour and a couple of hundred thousand net new insertions in each hour.

Let me know if there are some pointers on how we can improve the performance.
[image]
[image]

Thanks,
Kushal.

Comment: How many indices do you have? Instead of 20 r6g.large.search you can have 10 r6g.2xlarge.search. I don't think it helps you to have more small nodes instead fewer bigger ones. Also, your indexing rate is way lower and this doesn't depend on elastic/opensearch. Refresh interval is 900 sec means you can index much faster but search will be slower, much slower. To improve search, put it back to 1 sec and shards should be fine. Each node should have equal and less than 800 shards for a better performance.

Comment: We have 5 attributes where we have built an index. I would say all included this should be 3B+ indexed attributes. Help me understand, if we index at a very quick frequency of 1 sec, wouldn't the search in fact be slow as CPU cycles are going in that work? How would search become faster I guess if we index things faster?

Comment: Let me clear what I meant. With the cluster you have, indexing operations are almost negligible(We have 3 r6g.xlarge data nodes which handle 70k ops/min without any issue). Your indexing is only 8k max. So that's why I think you do not need a refresh interval of 900 seconds. Maybe 60 sec is enough. What is not very clear from your question is, you want to optimize for search or indexing? Also, why is your indexing rate is this much slow?

Comment: To be honest, I do not know what an attribute and indexed attribute is. In ES you have index which is made from one or more shards and it's the basic unit. So with this definition, do you say you have 3B+ indices? Also what do you mean by 60 shards in your question?